# Proper way to hide components from not auth users in vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I've been looking into changing my app fully to vue front, but there are some things that are bugging me, like:

In laravel blade now I am using (posts page):

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
<post data="{!! json_encode($post) !!}">
    @if(auth()->user()->id === $post->user->id)
        <edit-post></edit-post>
    @endif
</post>
@endforeach
```

Now if I want to convert this fully to vue I would need to:

-in master.blade.php where I use vue I would need to pass:

```
window.userData = {id: '{{auth()->user()->id}}'};
```

and then to check it inside vue, but what if client-side someone change that global object id to post-user-id, he will get component for editing, although it wont edit or affect back-end because of user validation, but it will show the form...

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

you could use vue's `v-if`. this would conditionally render html elements based on your parameter.

```
<post data="{!! json_encode($post) !!}">
    <template v-if="userId === postUserId">
       <edit-post></edit-post>
    </template>
</post>
```

> v-if is “real” conditional rendering because it ensures that event listeners and child components inside the conditional block are properly destroyed and re-created during toggles.

Comment: you didnt understaand, i know that but what if someone change userid to postid through console?

Comment: I think the only time you can change v-model values thru console is when you are in development mode.

Comment: i wasnt trying production mode so i cant tell if thats truth but same way it is client side there must be a way to change and i want to avoid it

Comment: If the page uses a production/minified build of Vue.js, devtools inspection is disabled by default so the Vue pane won't show up. you can try it by running `npm run production`. I don't think there is no way doing a client-side validation since vuejs is a javascript framework. If you're still worried, add a token for additional security, that way, even if a user manipulated the data, he should also know the token that you returned.

Comment: well i wasnt thinking of dev tools but from fonsole directly because you can access vue by __vue__.something even on production mode, i tested that on some vue made sites. But it seems like i can either do like this as we spoke about or to lets say when i fetch posts to check on backend is user owner, if it is to include that component as value that is returned and if not to just dont return it. And then to output component as value but same one needs to be imported and thats something which makes it the same way...

Comment: maybe the sites you visited forgot to turn on production mode or they don't have a minified vuejs. Have you tried running in production mode and can still change the data? If yes, then it would be a huge breach. You can tell the vue community that you can manipulate data.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no, a proficient enough user with access to a javascript console can run any code they want and do as they please within the frontend.

If you were doing something like sending everyone's private data to all users and hiding it selectively with Javascript that woukd be a Very Bad Idea. But as it is... if the backend will catch cases of users trying to actually edit a post that isn't theirs, then you'll be fine. All your authentication and authorization logic should be there anyway, and Vue would mostly take care of rendering

Answer (score 0):

You never rely on front to validate data. Ever.

You should look into API Based Development,

In your case, passing current user id to back end isn't necessary. Always check Auth::user() in your Laravel app. (On the backend). Malicious user cannot fake authenticated user.